# uniform 16bit hash function for strings

Tags: string, java-me, hash

I have about 50,000 words that I want to map each of them to a 16bit number and I'm seeking for a hash function to run on j2me.
To be more specific I'm looking for a hash function with below criteria:

1. few (or no) collisions
2. light CPU load
3. I have all of the words now
4. Avalanche effect is **not** important, since it's not about security. It' just a look-up table.

I've tested java Strign.hashCode(), murmur hash, jenkins one at a  time and a few simple hand-made ones but all of them have at least 30% collisions.
The minimal perfect hashing seems to have heavy CPU load for a small mobile phone too.

Can anybody help me with this?

note: As you know murmur algorithm needs a seed and different seeds have different uniformity. How can I find the seed with minimum collisions?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Would other data structures work for you? For example a trie?

Comment: This could be of interest for you: [Fastest possible string key lookup for known set of keys](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6714715/805681) and [Directed acyclic word graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acyclic_deterministic_finite_automaton)

Comment: @Omri Barel: Thank you for the comment. I want to minimize memory accesses. I guess if I can find a good hash function it would be much faster and accesses memory much less.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into an old-fashioned [CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crc16). They are very fast and reasonably collision-free. Just not quite at 16 bits, as this [experiment](http://apollo.backplane.com/matt/crc64.html) seems to indicate. But nevertheless, you might give it a try, maybe it's good enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be late, but for reference, MurmurHash 3 is sufficiently fast to satisfy your speed criteria. However due to the constraint you have imposed, collisions will be quite common, since 16 bits can represent a range of 65536 values, your 50000 words would create some collisions.

Solutions:

- use 20+ bits for the key (with 32 bits, there is one collision in a few million samples)
- write a test program to find a fit seed for 16 bits, here are some useful tools: http://code.google.com/p/smhasher/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function I use in C# to map file name to 16 bit number. In my tests it performed better than Pearson hashing.

```
    public static unsafe int Get16BitHash(string str)
    {
        int hash = 0;
        int len = str.Length;

        fixed (char* ch = str)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                hash = hash + ((hash) << 5) + *(ch + i) + ((*(ch + i)) << 7);
            }
        }

        return ((hash) ^ (hash >> 16)) & 0xffff;
    }
```

Comment: If you are returning the data type int, this is still returning a 32 bit number, not 16?

Comment: It is preferable to perform calculations with 32 bit integers for performance reasons. The returned 32 bit integer has only low 16 bit, the rest high 16 bit are all zeros.